# Can I send BTC from other node or wallet with my address?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain, bitcoind, testnet

I'm trying to send bitcoins from node2 with my address **using private key** noted that **my address** is created in node1.I followed this link:
"https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/How_to_import_private_keys" 
I dump private key in node1 using this command:

```
bitcoin-cli -testnet -rpcuser=test -rpcpassword=test123 dumpprivkey "2N7YvA6ZBjFvXE3wuNQH4csev1QUWtrzYgA"
```

Then I imported private key in node2 through this command:

```
bitcoin-cli -testnet -rpcuser=test -rpcpassword=test123 importprivkey cNKbGVQvQgJsJuRy25ggZ71BRA9UZyEPCMekdntnZDWjYTg9TpRu
```

now I want to send bitcoin from node2 with my address to different address

**can anyone please give me solution to make transaction using my address private key**
  ***thanking you in advance***

Comment: Does this help: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/58755 ?

Answer (score 1):

I performed the scenario described, using these commands:

```
// create a new wallet. Extra options are needed to not create a descriptor-based wallet, to be able to dump privkey
bitcoin-cli -testnet -rpcuser=XXX -rpcpassword=XXX createwallet "test1" false false "" false false
bitcoin-cli  ...  getwalletinfo
// generate an address
bitcoin-cli  ...  getnewaddress
--> tb1qha...zxejw7
// dump its private key
bitcoin-cli  ...  dumpprivkey "tb1qha...zxejw7"
--> cRJzVP...cZTcV5
// send some funds to this address
bitcoin-cli  ...  getwalletinfo

// in another instance, create another wallet
bitcoin-cli  ...  createwallet "test2" false false "" false false
bitcoin-cli  ...  getwalletinfo
// import privkey of previous address. This can take a long time (many minutes), due to rescanning
bitcoin-cli  ...  importprivkey "cRJzVP...cZTcV5"
bitcoin-cli  ...  getwalletinfo
--> balance of the address shows up here
// Perform a send to another address
bitcoin-cli  ...  sendtoaddress "tb1qp2...n9qw92" 0.0001 "" "" true
bitcoin-cli  ...  getwalletinfo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use createrawtransaction to create a raw transaction, in which you can specify your custom inputs and outputs.
In this case you would specify the input to be the address from node2, and output/outputs to be addresses you are sending bitcoins to. Use signrawtransaction to sign raw transaction it using your imported private key and sendrawtransaction to send it to the network.